# Uploading, reading and naming multiple files from a Network directory in R

Tags: r, file, for-loop, file-upload, directory

I am trying to read several `.xlsx` files from a network directory that has this path:

`\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting`
Inside this folder there are several other folders (around 15) and in each of these folders are several files but each folder does have a `.xlsx` file with a name that starts with "overall_counts_123" the "123" could be any number but the name of the files will always start with "overall_counts" and my goal is to have all files uploaded to Rstudio and rename them with the tag "file1", "file2" etc, I apologize if I'm not being clear let me set an example:

If there are 3 folders in the directory and each folder has "n" files that start with "overall_counts" I would like to get only something like this:

```
\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting\folder1\overall_counts1.xlsx

\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting\folder2\overall_counts1.xlsx

\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting\folder2\overall_counts15.xlsx

\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting\folder3\overall_counts1008.xlsx
```

I'm using this code:

```
file_paths<-fs::dir_ls("\\181.01.2\Global_Office_Net\Accounting")

FILES<-file_paths %>% 
map(function(path){
  read_xlsx(path)})
```

But instead of looking in each folder for the files that start with "overall_counts" this is uploading everything and somehow making a list of them... when what I really looking for is to have each desired file uploaded as file2, file2 and so on in separates dataframes I will be so thankful if you could please reference an article on how to upload files based in a criteria for the name of the file and upload them separately thank you so much guys I truly owe you this one

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

Get a list of the files that match, looking in all the subfolders (recursive = TRUE)

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "\\\\181.01.2\\Global_Office_Net\\Accounting\\", 
                        pattern = "overall_counts[0-9]+\\.xlsx", 
                        recursive = TRUE)
```

Tag with "file1", "file2", etc.

```
fns <- setNames(filenames, paste0("file", 1:length(filenames)))
```

Now read these files into R:

```
library(readxl)
dfs <- lapply(fns, read_xlsx)
```

This results in a list of dataframes (tibbles) like so: `dfs$file1`, `dfs$file2`, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).